# Why can a child class not access a parent class propety without a construct method?

Tags: php, class, oop

This might be basic knowledge, but I am curious as I do not know it yet myself. Why in PHP (and assuredly other languages) when using classes must a child class use a construct method to access the parent class' properties. In case this is unclear I will include an example.

```
    <?php
     class aClass
      {
       protected $aProperty = "Some value";
      }
     class aDifferentClass extends aClass
      {
       public $aDifferentProperty;
       public function __construct()
        {
         $this->$aDifferentProperty = $this->aProperty;
      }
    ?>//Works.
```

Instead of:

```
    <?php
     class aClass
      {
       protected $aProperty = "Some value";
      }
     class aDifferentClass extends aClass
      {
       public $aDifferentProperty = $this->$aProperty;
      }
    ?>//Doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a matter of needing the constructor its a matter of WHEN you're trying to access it. A class is a blueprint for an object -- when you're trying to assign the property, as you've done in your example above, ie.

```
public $aDifferentProperty = $this->aProperty;
```

There is no object, and thus "this" does not yet exist. But, instead, this would work:

```
class A {
  protected $a_property = "BOOYEA!";
}

class B extends A {
   public function show_me_a_prop() {
      echo $this->a_property;
   }
}

$object = new B();
$object->show_me_a_prop();
```

So, to answer your question, you must wait until after the object has been constructed to access the properties because until its constructed, its not an object, just a blueprint for an object.

Now, to take this a bit further, you'd not allowed to assign variables directly to properties (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php ) but you can assign a constant. So here's a similar example which does work:

```
class A {
  const a_property = "BOOYEA!";
}

class B extends A {
   public $b_property = self::a_property;
}

$object = new B();
echo $object->b_property;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "__construct" was introduced in PHP5 and it is the right way to define your constructors (in PHP4 you used the name of the class for a constructor).

You are NOT REQUIRED to define a constructor in your class, but if you wish to pass any parameters on object construction THEN YOU NEED ONE.

Also...If further down the track you change the class the child class inherits from, you don't have to change the construct call to the parent.

much easier to call `parent::__construct()` instead of `parent::ClassName()`, as it is reusable among classes and the parent can be changed easily.

Comment: While interesting information, this does not answer my question.

Comment: Well, I dont see how it doesn't???  You asked why must you call construct to access a parent properties.  The real answer is you don't have to.....you can just call the parent by name.....but you have to call it because you have to instantiate it........__construct() is just a way to do that without relying on the Name, allowing you to keep your code more updateable

Comment: I was asking why I can't simply define a child property with a value of a parent property without the construct method.

Comment: Still not what I am asking. Was I not clear enough? Look at my example.

Comment: I just don't understand why you would need to...when you have access to it already?? Thats the reason for extending a class in the first place no?  Why double assign?  If you know what I mean....or is it that you are just wondering......

Comment: I don't know if there is any practical use. I am simply curious.

Comment: @KyleK you may like to see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120093/create-a-link-for-a-user-as-this-http-mysite-com-profile-phpid-12 lol

Comment: Your question is ambiguous though, you might wanna change it.   Because you say...."Why must a child class use a construct method to access the parent class' properties"  ....which is not true, it doesn't have to construct to access.  Your question should be..."Why must a child class use __contruct() to assign a parents class property to a child class property outside of a function"  Because you can assign inside any function, without calling __construct()